# How extend a function declared inside "options" in mootools?

Tags: javascript, mootools, validation

I want to extend the "**showError**" function of "**Form.Validator.Inline**" in mootools. That function is declared inside "**options**".

I tried the below code, but it is not working.

```
var exFormValidator = new Class({
            Extends:  Form.Validator.Inline,
            options: {
                    showError: function(element) {
                        var error = element.getPrevious();
                        if(error != null){
                            error.dispose();
                        }
                        this.parent(element);
                    }
                }
        });
```

I can make it work by copying the code from "**mootools-more**" like below:

```
        var exFormValidator = new Class({
            Extends:  Form.Validator.Inline,
            options: {
                    showError: function(element) {
                        var error = element.getPrevious();
                        if(error != null){
                            error.dispose();
                        }
                        if (element.reveal) element.reveal();
                        else element.setStyle('display', 'block');
                    }
                }
        });
```

but I don't think that is the way of doing things. Is there any alternative/correct way to do it ?

Comment: Why do you think that's not the correct way to do it?

Comment: If we are updating the mootools-more file and in that file the funtionality changes, we have to do the same work; but instead of that if the parent functionality works that'll be better

Comment: Do you try to extend Form.Validator.Inline to have the showError method?

Comment: I am experimenting with the validator

Answer (score 0):

have found an answer. There is a "**onShowAdvice()**" event in "**Form.Validator.Inline**". You have to extend it as follows:

```
        var formValidator = new Form.Validator.Inline(regForm, {
                errorPrefix: '',
                serial: false,
                onShowAdvice: function(element, advice) {
                    var error = advice.getPrevious();
                    if(error != null) {
                        error.dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
```

The **showAdvice** function is calling showError. So calling it will do the thing; but still the question remains. Is it possible to extend function in "**options**" ?